# HTML Desktop Application with JAVA backend

Tags: java, html, css, netbeans, point-of-sale

I'm looking to develop a Point-Of-Sale program using an HTML front end UI with java backend functionality (Java is really the only programming language I have experience with and would like to do all my coding in java).

I am an amateur developer with very little experience. I have only used netbeans before, but I have done a few tutorials in HTML and CSS.

I would like the application to function as a normal desktop application, and I don't necessarily want it to run in a browser. Is there any way to do this? How would I merge HTML and JAVA functionality as an offline desktop application?

Comment: Too broad really for a coding Q&A, but without knowing any of your other constraints, my suggestion is maybe an electron.js app with a Java backend on a server somewhere, exposed via a HTTP API (and with ajax calls to communicate between the the UI and backend). You'll need to know at least a bit of JavaScript if you want to do anything nice as a HTML frontend. Electron lets you build desktop apps using HTML etc. I've no idea whether NetBeans would be a practical IDE for that side of it, although no doubt it would be fine for the backend service.

Comment: However, if you're intent is to build a desktop-based app, why the requirement for HTML? Why not use a native GUI library (such as JavaFX suggested below) or one of the other toolkits available? If you want to build a HTML app, it might be more flexible to make it a web app which runs in a browser. Again without knowing what other constraints you have, it's impossible to make a definitive recommendation.

Answer (score -1):

You might try JavaFX. [Here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javafx/) is a link to the TutorialsPoint tutorial on it. Another option could be the Swing GUI builder already built into the Netbeans IDE. In your java package right-click and New > JFrame Form. In the design tab, you can drag-and-drop the components you need onto the JFrame. Not the most modern, but easy for beginners.